# How do I do automate numbering in Excel with the mouse?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I recently migrated to office 2010. How do I insert the numbers in excel by holding the mouse, which was possible in the older version?

Comment: As explained in either answer: Type `1` in A1, type `2` in A2, drag the bottom right corner anchor down and it will fill the series. As a result A3 will have `3`, A4 will have `4` and so on...

Answer (score 2):

The feature is still there. Just do as the picture below shows.

[image]

Comment: I would like to have 1,2,3,4,etc and not 1,1,1,1,1

Comment: That is why I've highlighted `Fill Series`. Click it.

Answer (score 0):

Refer my screenshots:-

### Before Drag n Drop

[image]

### After Drag n Drop

[image]

Comment: @Sivaand Bibhas, i could not extend the selection beyond selected text. I was comfortable in my old version. Is it a bug in my new system?

Comment: @Anil: Can you please provide a screenshot? It will be more clear for us..